# Swiper.js slide is making the slides jump by 1 and skipping the next slide while swiping right but working fine on left swipe

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, swiper.js

I have used this code for swiper :

```
new Swiper("#swiper-pricing", {
    slidesPerView: 1.3,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: true,
    keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
    },
    loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,  
    a11y: {
        prevSlideMessage: 'Previous slide',
        nextSlideMessage: 'Next slide',
      },
    navigation: {
        nextEl: "#nav-right",
        prevEl: "#nav-left"
    },
    pagination: {
        el: "#swiper-pricing .swiper-custom-pagination",
        clickable: true,
    },
    
})
```

I am using CSS :   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>`
and, JS : `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>`

I thought at first that the booststrap 5.3 which I am using with it is conflicting but its not the case and I have even tried removing all the CSS but it was still not working.

For note I need the 1.3 slidesperView value

I want the slides to swipe perfectly and not skip it on RIGHT SWIPE which is perfectly working on left swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing just happened to me, slide was acting funny on right swipe. The problem is too big elements in single row, coupled with slidesPerView and spaceBetween properties. When I lowered those 2 to fit a screen it was working ok.